# visual studio not creating .exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exe

I am developing windows forms application in C#. It always produced .exe in \bin\release. But now it is not creating .exe file for this specific project. There is no error and even warning. I also checked the the build output folder and is the same. I tried build and rebuild solution. if I open other project and run it creates exe.

```
build options:
configuration= active release,   
platform= active any cpu,
output folder= \bin\release,
generate serialization assembly= auto,
```

Comment: Are you running your program in Debug or Release mode? Do you get any other files there?

Comment: Release mode. but i also tried Debug mode.

Comment: What do the build options say?

Comment: Does your program run?

Comment: yes my program run correctly.

Comment: build options
configuration= active release,    plateform= active any cpu,
output folder= \bin\release,
generate serialization assembly= auto

Comment: Your output folder shouldn't be preceded with a "\" change it to "bin\release" other wise you probably get your executable file in C:\bin\release

Comment: Well thanks. thats my typo-error, in fact it is  bin\Release\