# Create .exe manually in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, exe

When we build solution, exe is created automatically in `\bin\Release` or `\bin\Debug`. Is there any way to create .exe manually(not publishing) in visual studio. I already posted this question
[visual studio not creating .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558027/visual-studio-not-creating-exe)

Manually mean command line or some thing like..... other than using build

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"? You can use a command line, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you mean build [commanline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [visual studio not creating .exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558027/visual-studio-not-creating-exe)

Comment: Why do you tag VS12 when your title states Visual Studio 2013? This is kinda confusing. I'm not sure what your question is? Can you 'change' it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not so clear.

But if you meaning to commandline you can build with MSBuild, DEVENV and NMake ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx))

you also can build with csc.exe ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx))